# get_posts always returning the same number of posts = 5

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I don't understand why the code below is always displaying the same number of returned post = 5. When I change the `$variable` value to another `post id` of a post with an author with another `author_id`, I always get 5 returned posts, even if the authors have tens of posts. What am I doing wrong?

```
$variable=328;
$post = get_post($variable);

$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);

$args = array(
'author' => $author->id ); 

global $post;

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$count= count($myposts);

echo '<pre dir="ltr">';
print_r($myposts);
echo '</pre>';

echo $count;
```

Your help is really apprecieted.

Comment: Have you tried examining the queries using the WP Debug Bar and Debug Bar Extender? This might shed some light on what's happening. Likely it's using the default # of posts which is defined in the backend under Settings > Reading.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback. I have the # of posts in backend set to 100.  I dont have WP Debug Bar and Debug Bar Extender. those are WP plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts/) has some defaults set, including `numberposts` equal to `5`. Since it's not considered to be a loop by itself those are independent and not affected by admin settings.

So simply pass in arguments `numberposts`/`posts_per_page` (same thing) number for how many posts you want or `-1` for all matching posts.

Comment: I used WP_query before reading your answer, and it is working. thank you anyway for giving me this precious info Rarst.

Answer (score 0):

Do this and get 50 posts. Give any number what you want to return

$args = array(
'numberposts'   => 50,

'author' => $author->id
);